is observing animated arwah which is only drawing halal if it doesn't cause me to wish to commit zina along real (not that i could pull either way)
pretty much stated everything in the title, did some research but no one answered me in a way my small brain could digest or said blatantly wrong things or just not exactly the same as my situation.
so can someone give a fatwah preferably a sunni fatwah
